# Hibernate do not insert child object

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am having the following Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public class School {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sch_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer schoolId;

    ... 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "stu_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer studentId;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id", referencedColumnName = "sch_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private School school;
}
```

Now when I am saving a new student object, the generated insert query for the student table does not contain the field 'school_id'.

```
SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(student),
```

how can I include 'school_id' to the insert query. Please note I do not want to insert/update the school object. I just set schoolId in the school object and it is set into the students school object.

Comment: Research the use of `cascade` in your annotations for child objects.

Comment: Well, since you specifically told Hibernate _school_id_ is NOT insertable, that's hardly surprising. I suggest you look up what `insertable = false` actually does, it has nothing to do with updating the referenced entity